# Is it possible to use Linux to route between my office (which uses IPSec) and home network?

Tags: linux, vpn, ipsec

First of all, apologies if this seems vague - I'm not an admin of anything more than a home network.

I have a Ubuntu box sitting on my network which does various odd tasks for me - svn serving, some file serving, Apache/MySQL/PHP which is all raring to go.

I've started a new job and at the moment I'm using ShrewSoft VPN software to establish a VPN link to the office as I need it. I'd prefer to have something always running on my home network just for convenience. My home modem/router doesn't support holding a VPN connection open.

What I would like to do is set up my Linux box to hold open a VPN connection to my office and keep it open permanently, and then all applicable traffic for the office be routed through this box.

I'm not sure if this is possible, or how to configure the routing on the desktop PCs (Windows 7).

Would appreciate any guides, etc that could help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This scenario that you describe is completely possible, in order to get through it you just need some simple steps

1. Configure the VPN on the Linux box
2. Since you're routing a network through this box make sure that you have NAT working to the VPN tunnel interface
3. Just add a static permanent route on each of your PCs to route the traffic through that linux box, if you want that by de-facto just add a static route to your router

Also make sure that you have permission from your work to do this since you're exposing the office network to all your home PCs!

Answer (score 0):

There are also a lot of cheap routers, some of them even support linux-based open firmware,  that will allow you to run site-to-site IPSEC tunnels.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a dynamic DNS service like dnydns.org unless your home has a static address.

If you have an older PC to use as a dedicated router, you may like PFSense - a FreeBSD based router OS. It has IPSEC VPN built-in and all the other bells & whistles you could want.